# Uncheck all checkboxes in repeater except checkbox being checked

Tags: c#, jquery, vb.net, user-interface, repeater

I know my question reads a bit like that 'how much wood can a woodchuck chuck' line, please excuse that...

I have a repeater with checkboxes.  There are numerous rows in this repeater - I never know how many - I want only one checkbox checked at any time. If the user changes the checked checkbox, any pre-existing checks are unchecked therefore maintaining a single checked checkbox.

I am using VB, but comfortable to port any C#. I want to use JQuery.  I have been looking on Google, but only ever seem to find ALL checked, ALL unchecked systems.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want checkboxes that work like radiobuttons... well, why not just use radiobuttons?

Comment: I've found radiobuttons in a repeater don't always behave themselves. Besides, the solution called for checkboxes because they have been styled using an alternative UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, add some class to all checkboxes of group-with-one-checked to determine it. For example, `class="radio-similar"`.

Then:

```
$('.radio-similar').change(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.radio-similar').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Reko. I gave the answer to kpower because of his extra explanation, but I up-voted your answer also.  Many thanks.